# Can my user Id on programmers be correlated with my user Id on stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

I use the same google Id, but I've (attempted) to remove the identifying info from my profile on Programmers.  Can it still be correlated with my SO identity? (by random people, obviously SO staff could) Or another way to ask the question is, who am I?

Since SO is theoretically an extension to my future resume, I'd rather not have my identity there associated with my identity on programmers.stackexchange.com, which in my opinion, is where the argumentative, combative and other bad-behavior-encouraging questions end up.

I suppose if one doesn't want to get into a bar fight, don't go to bars, but on the other hand, sitting out the discussion isn't an attractive option either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want is to use a single OpenID and have all your SE accounts associated *except* for your Programmer's account, then sorry, [you can't do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52272/stop-repeatedly-auto-associating-accounts-on-login).

If you're okay with disassociating all of your accounts, then go to [your Programmer's account page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/191?tab=accounts), where you should see a link/button/box at the very bottom that says [`Clear all associations`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/191?tab=accounts#clear-associations). Clicking that *should* do the trick.

Another approach is to create a new OpenID and use it just for Programmers.

But to answer the general question: anyone can go to [one of your account pages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/191?tab=accounts) and see all your associated accounts at once.

Comment: Clear associations doesn't work--the page *always* shows associations, clearing associations just changes the layout. It appears that the only way to break the link is to request for the account to be deleted.

Comment: Nix, that. Had to launch chrome in icognito mode to keep it from automatically logging in-- the related accounts tab appears to be blank for the moment..  Actually I'm not sure what is going on anymore.  I click the clear associations when ever I see it.  I've deleted all my comments, questions and answers from this account and I'll create a new account for programmers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly it's very easy.

I understand your point but maybe the solution to your problem is to avoid posting answers you wouldn't assume in the future?

Comment: When you end up in a flame war, no one really gets to say, "well he started it," even if you are the recipient of the hostility because it makes one look provocative.

Comment: Well, by default it is easy.  I suppose if you can figure out who I am by this link, then indeed, I guess it is still easy: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/191?tab=accounts

Comment: No, now it's fine, I can't access your profiles anymore.